# How to override content defined in Remarks tag for a Swagger output

Tags: c#, api, swagger

In my sources I define some documentation data within **remark** tags, so they show in the api Swagger pages in the corresponding **header** section.

Is there a way to fill that header section programmatically by overriding any of the swagger config properties?
That will allow us to define the content somewhere outside the source code.

Comment: not exactly what I intended, but ended up with a solution that allows me to define html formatted remarks in an external xml file and not in the source code.

Comment: Used <include> tag in source file:
 /// <include file='SwaggerExtensions/xml_include_tag.doc' path='SwaggerHeaderDoc/Methods[@name="GetXXXXXId"]/*' /> 
 where external xml file: 
 <SwaggerHeaderDoc>  
    <Methods name="GetLoanById">
        <remarks>
            <h1>This is a heading</h1>            
            ....
        </remarks>
    </Methods>
</SwaggerHeaderDoc> 
More than anything, this is a consolation solution, since it's not what I initially wanted

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is any way to do this because Swagger API pulls out the information from the comments within the code and the code. To update the API by any other way defeats the purpose of the API.

Comment: don't agree with your last sentence, but thank you for your two cents.

Comment: I concluded it with that sentence because of this sentence on their website  - "The Swagger specification creates a RESTful interface for easily developing and consuming an API by **effectively mapping all the resources and operations associated with it."**